# Simple login and logout capabilities for my web app(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, security, authentication, jsf-2, ejb-3.0

This morning i rode chapters 39,40 and 41 of the JEE6 tutorial. But i am very, very confused. I don't have a background on web-app security with JEE6, and i am having big difficulties to understand and implement.

I need to create an authorization mechanism for my web app, my scenario is also not very simple for a begginer in JEE6 like me so i decided to try to find the easiest way to do it.

I thought to explain my idea, so you can correct me and give me some advice on how it would be the best easiest way to do it.

Idea:

My web app uses a primefaces component called dock that pops a log in dialog when the use clicks in the last item. Also this navigation tool is located in a JSF template that is used by all the other pages in the application.

```
    <h:body>
<p:dock position="top"> 
    <p:menuitem value="Naslovna" icon="unsecuredimages/naslovna.png" url="main.xhtml"
        alt="The image could not be found." />
    <p:menuitem value="Register" icon="unsecuredimages/register.png"
        url="registration.xhtml" alt="The image could not be found." />
    <p:menuitem value="Cesta pitanja" icon="unsecuredimages/faq.png"
        url="faq.xhtml" alt="The image could not be found." />
        <!-- The login will not have a page, it will pop up a login dialog -->
    <p:menuitem value="Login" icon="unsecuredimages/login.png" url="#" onclick="dlg.show()"/>       
</p:dock>
<p:dialog header="Prijavite se" widgetVar="dlg"  modal="true" draggable="false" resizable="false" effect="SLIDE">  
     <h:outputText value="Em@il:" /><h:inputText id="email" value=""/>
     <br/>  
     <h:outputText value="Lozinka:" /><h:inputText id="password" value=""/>
     <br/> 
     <h:commandButton value="Prijavi se" />
</p:dialog>     
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>  
<ui:insert name="mainForm" />
<ui:insert name="registrationForm" />
<ui:insert name="registrationBuyerForm" />
<ui:insert name="registrationSellerForm" />
<ui:insert name="faqForm" />
<ui:insert name="registrationSuccessForm" />
  </h:body>
```

That JSF i think should have a backing bean that handles the email and the password over to an EJB.

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import ejbinterfaces.IAuthentificationEJB;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityController {
@EJB
private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;
private String email;
private String password;

public void logIn() {
    authentificationEJB.saveUserState(email, password);
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

Then the EJB should do the login and log out(This is where i get very confused):

```
@Stateful(name = "ejbs/AuthentificationEJB")
public class AuthentificationEJB implements IAuthentificationEJB {      
//Login
public boolean saveUserState(String email,String password) {
    //1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
    //2-If the query returns the user object, store it somewhere in the session(HOW?)
    //3-return true if the user state was saved
    //4-return false otherwise
    return false;
}


//Logout
public void releaseUserState() {
    //1-Check if there is something saved in the session(or wherever the state is saved)
    //2-If 1 then flush it
}

//Check if user is logged in
public boolean checkAuthentificationStatus() {
    //1-Check if there is something saved in the session(This means the user is logged in)
    //2-If there is not a user already loged, then return false
    return false;
}
```

}

I decided not to use a jdbc realm or other of the authentification mechanisms explained in the JEE6 tutorial, because i get really confused, so i think that for now it is easier for me to do it manually. This are some doubts i have about my approach:

- Is this approach correct(Can it be done this way)?
- Should the EJB be @Stateless or @Statefull in this case(The user retrived from the database ony has 2 String fields)?
- Where should i store the id of the retrieved user from the database, to last until the user decides to logout?
- If i have to store the user state in the session until he/she decides to logout, how can i do it?
- With this approach will the session for the user be delated when closes the browser without logging out(If no, how can i expire his/her session automatically after a while if there is not activity?)

Ill appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Not addressing your issue here, but I recommend that you try to use the container approach to security and let them manage it (after all, frameworks are there to do this for you). If you are having trouble setting up a jdbc realm, there is one realm that can be set to read a properties file that is pretty easy to setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some pieces of the puzzle:

> Is this approach correct(Can it be
>   done this way)?

Yes it can. You can choose between container managed security or application managed.

> Should the EJB be @Stateless or
>   @Statefull in this case(The user
>   retrived from the database ony has 2
>   String fields)?

If you store the id of the currently logged in user in session context (see below), I think you can do it with a stateless bean (from theory).

> Where should i store the id of the
>   retrieved user from the database, to
>   last until the user decides to logout?

You can store it in session context:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userID", email);
```

Use `getSessionMap()#get("userID")` in order to check the stored userID.

> With this approach will the session
>   for the user be delated when closes
>   the browser without logging out(If no,
>   how can i expire his/her session
>   automatically after a while if there
>   is not activity?)

No, the session will expire automatically when reaching a timeout. The timeout can be set in your web.xml:

```
<session-config>
   <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This setting means, that sessions will time out after 60 minutes of server inactivity.

Comment: This is was helpful answer, thank you. I will start implementing my application managed authentification today. I just have another little doubt regarding to the timeout. If i set the time out on 60, will the user be automatically be logged out even if he/she is currently ussing the application, or the time out starts its count when there is innactivity?

Comment: Correct would be _server-inactivity_. The timeout starts from the last time the server was involved. Once I had a very long form without ajax and the user didn't manage it to fill within 60 minutes and the session expired ...

Comment: I see, that is good i dont have to worry about that, if the session expires it will be the users fault. He will have to login again :)

You mentioned a form without ajax, i dont understand why would ajax make a difference when regarding to session timeout?

Comment: Ajax statements usually trigger (partial) server-requests.